# Disable "All files" when using FileNameExtensionFilter in java

Tags: java, swing, file-type

I am using the [FileNameExtensionFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) to filter the file type but when the user selects the open button, they have the option to select "All files" from the file type. is there a way to disable that option?

```
 FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", "jpg", "jpeg");
 JFileChooser fileChooser = ...;
 fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
```

so something to add to above code which disallow user to select any other file?

Comment: JFileChooser. setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take a look at [`JFileChooser#setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(boolean))

> Determines whether the AcceptAll FileFilter is used as an available
>   choice in the choosable filter list. If false, the AcceptAll file
>   filter is removed from the list of available file filters. If true,
>   the AcceptAll file filter will become the the actively used file
>   filter.

Comment: *"..will become **the the** actively used file filter"*  I was about to change that till I realized that was a direct quote from the docs. (and it is the same in the [1.8 docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed-boolean-))!  Now I'm not so sure it should be touched..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Raise a ticket

Comment: I was considering that, but then, I'd be more interested in Oracle answering my request to expand the layout tutorial to include a page/section on combining layouts.  :-/

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hahaha...I'd like to see that